# Using iframe in Django, keep getting 'TemplateDoesNotExist'

Tags: python, html, django

I am using iFrame with Django 2.0.13. I keep getting TemplateDoesNotExist error, and I don't see what I'm missing.

I've looked at other answers here on StackOverFlow and I seem to be doing everything.

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from NatureApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('NatureApp/', include('NatureApp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'Map2.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Map2.html"), name='Map2'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

# def index(request):
#     return HttpResponse("Hello World!")

def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_me':"Hello I am from views.py!"}
    return render(request,'NatureApp/index.html',context=my_dict)
```

`Map2.html` should being showing. I see `index.html` fine, but inside the IFrame I see the `TemplateDoesNotExist` message.

I'm new to Django, I'm trying to include all code needed for troubleshooting.

Comment: Where is IFrame related code, Could you please update your question to include template file?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating Map2 view in views.py. There could be problem with `TemplateView.as_view()`

Comment: Thanks! I did that, and changed urls.py :
    path(r'Map2', views.Map2, name='Map2'),
I guess I didn't need the TemplateView.as_view() at all.